# Find which script is activating the object

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a disabled gameobject in the scene. When i started the game that gameobject becomes enabled somehow. How do i find which script enables that object?. Is there a trick to find ? My code is too spaghetti even i dont understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all

> My code is too spaghetti even i dont understand.

well ... this is bad so clean this up first before doing anything else ^^

---

Simplest way I can imagine would be a simple debugger component/method call:

```c#
public class WhoIsEnablingThis : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Debug.Log("I just got enabled!", this);
    }
}
```

and put this on the according `GameObject`.

This causes a log message being printed to the console including a callstack where you might already be able to see from which method exactly the object was enabled.

Example:

> I just got enabled!
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object, Object)
>   WhoIsEnablingThis:OnEnable() (at Assets/WhoIsEnablingThis.cs:10)
>   UnityEngine.GameObject:SetActive(Boolean)
>   **Enabler:Start() (at Assets/Enabler.cs:12)**

in my example script `Enabler.cs` indeed I have the line 12 in `Start`:

```c#
private void Start()
{
    example.SetActive(true);
}
```

---

The next step if the console is not enough would then be to set a [breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019) to the `Debug.Log` line and [debug your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) line by line e.g. with VisualStudio.

Once this line's breakpoint is hit in VisualStudio simply enable the [callstack view](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window?view=vs-2019) and you can directly go through all methods leading to this enabling.

[image]

Once you reached the component which is originally causing the call (in my case the `Enabler` class) you can look at the `name` field of `MonoBehaviour` classes so you will know exactly which `GameObject` this component is attached to. If you have multiple with the same name at least you can still bubble up through the `transform.parent` properties until you have the information you need.

[image]

Comment: @Kamiky no it won't be ... at least for me you can see the Unity internal stack and then further ahead back to where the object was enabled ... but thanks for the downvote ^^

Comment: I found my error before your answer. But i learned very important thing from you. Thank you !

Comment: @Kamiky no you can find which line is activating the gameobject with derHugo's method.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking at derHugo's response above who can't see the CallStack info in the Console, you need to enable it via the **options / hamburger menu for the Console > Stack Trace Logging > Log > ScriptOnly**.

[screencap of console options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wbsm.png)